# Why is my loss so high?

Tags: neural-network, hyperparameter, loss-function

I am struggling to understand why I am getting such a high loss/val_loss rate on my training. I am training a regression network. I've normalized the input data to range between -1 to 1, and left the output data unaltered, its range is approximately between -100 and 100.

I chose to normalize the input so that I could use tanh as the activation function since it outputs within this range.

[image]

[image]

The neural network consists of 3 layers.

```
  print "Model definition!"
    model = Sequential()

    #act = PReLU(init='normal', weights=None)
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=400,input_dim=400, init="normal",activation=K.tanh))

    #act1 = PReLU(init='normal', weights=None)
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=400,input_dim=400, init="normal",activation=K.tanh))

    #act2 = PReLU(init='normal', weights=None)
    #model.add(Dense(output_dim=400, input_dim=400, init="normal",activation=K.tanh))

    act4=ELU(100)
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=13, input_dim=400, init="normal",activation=act4))
```

The mapping between the input and output consists of mapping audio samples into MFCC features.  The samples are the ones i've normalized to the aforementioned range.

Why am I getting these results?

Am I doing anything that is unclear?

Normalizing the output_range +-1:

[image]
Why is the val_loss loss lower than the loss?

Comment: As I said in comments to previous question, you are taking on a tough challenge. Your title question "Why is my loss so high?" is a very broad question, and there are loads of things to investigate for your project. As you are exploring an unusual prediction goal, it is doubtful that anyone can give you better than guesswork or pointers to things to try.

Comment: As Neil said it's hard to say what could be wrong, there's no obvious mistake in what you've done. My suggestion is to try a higher initial learning rate, this can help when you have so many parameters. Worst case scenario is that the learning rate is too high and your LR scheduling will kick in to reduce it.

Comment: @Hugh Great idea..  I guess i will try it out. 
I tried normalizing the output aswell.. The dataset i had ranged between +-100.. So i scaled it down to +-1 and used a tanh as a activation function for the output layer, which shrinked the loss to around 0.01..

Comment: why create the input layer multiple times?  It should be created only once. what is your training set and I will show you how to setup a dense network

Answer (score 0):

As your two training curves show, neural networks are sensitive to a range of both features and targets. Normalizing both features and targets can facilitate learning.